# Why does awk print a new line before the command is finished?

Tags: bash, awk, tcsh

I have a list of awk commands that are in the same format as follows:

```
awk '$2==1 && $3>=145044110 && $4<=145861130 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,"Del\_11.1"}' $input>>$input.new.txt
```

I want the output of these awk statements to all be on one line, however, the output is like this:

```
subj1 1 1450441100 145861130
Del_11.1
```

I want `"Dell_11.1"` to be on the same line as the rest of the output. Any ideas as to why it keeps getting printing to a new line?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us the input ?

Comment: Is the file 'DOS' format with CRLF line endings by any chance?  I can't replicate your problem even with CRLF line endings, but there isn't an obvious reason for the behaviour.  What platform are you testing on?  Which version of `awk`, do you know?  It 'ought' not to be doing it.

Comment: Does $4 have a bunch of trailing whitespace? Also, underscore is not a special character in a string, so you don't need to escape it.

Comment: have you tried `print($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" Del\_11.1")`?